# No se aplica la propiedad $('#input').val('') en JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un input de tipo text el cual quiero dejar su valor vacío, aplicando la propiedad  $('#id_input').val('') en JQuery pero no le aplica los cambios, creo que esto pasa porque ese input le apliqué la propiedad autocomplete.

al momento de limpiar todos los input del formulario con .val('') se aplica para casi todos los input en excepción uno que es el que le aplico la propiedad autocomplete, por lo que me toca refrescar la pagina con F5 para que se pueda borrar el valor de ese campo.

Mi Input Tex

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Vehiculo</label>
      <input id="txtVehiculo" name="txtVehiculo" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Por mi lado, creé un método llamado autocomplete para cargar todos los vehículos a ese input que acabo de mostrar, le paso cómo parámetro dos input type text y un array:

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtVehiculo"), getVehiculos(), document.getElementById("txtPlacaVehiculoImplicado"));
```

Este es el código del método que convierte el input type text en un autocomplete y sé que hay algo dentro de ese código que está bloqueando el input y no me deja aplicarle la propiedad .val('') para limpiar el valor cuando envío los datos exitosamente.

```
function autocomplete(campo, arreglo, campo_oculto) {
var currentFocus;
campo.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
        return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i].nombre.toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase())) {
            var posicion_inicial = arreglo[i].nombre.indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
            var posicion_final = posicion_inicial + val.length;
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.innerHTML = arreglo[i].nombre.substr(0, posicion_inicial);
            b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arreglo[i].nombre.substring(posicion_inicial, posicion_final) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arreglo[i].nombre.substr(posicion_final);
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='" + arreglo[i].id + "' value='" + arreglo[i].nombre + "'>";
            b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                campo.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                campo.id = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
                campo.readOnly = true;
                campo_oculto.value = campo.id;
                closeAllLists();
            });
            a.appendChild(b);
        }
    }
});
campo.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x)
        x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
            if (x)
                x[currentFocus].click();
        }
    }
});
function addActive(x) {
    if (!x)
        return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length)
        currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0)
        currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
}
function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
}
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != campo) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}
```

Luego al finalizar de guardar aplico este método para limpiar los valores pero el input en mención no aplica los cambios.

```
function limpiardespuesdeguardar() {
  $('#txtPlacavehiculo').val('');//aplica los cambios
  $('#txtVehiculo').val(''); //NO APLICA LOS CAMBIOS
  $('#txtEmpresa').val(''); //aplica los cambios
  $('#txtTipovehiculo').val(''); //aplica los cambios
  $('#txtModelo').val(''); //aplica los cambios
  $('#txtMarca').val(''); //aplica los cambios
  $('#txtPlacaVehiculoImplicado').val(''); //aplica los cambios
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con la solución!

Comment: ¿Es necesario que coloque mas codigo? creo que la pregunta se entiende men, es muy especifica

Comment: Revisa si en toda la página existe otro input con el mismo ID.

Comment: No, no existe fue lo primero que revisé, casualmente siempre me pasa lo mismo en todas las paginas que aplico el método autocomplete.

Comment: Probaste borrar el campo sin jquery?

Comment: Si, ya lo probé con: document.getElementById("txtVehiculo").value = ""; y sigue igual el problema

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en los `"autocomplete-list"` que deberían ser `" autocomplete-list"`

(Notese el espacio en blanco que hay antes). Quedaría así:

```
function autocomplete(campo, arreglo, campo_oculto) {
var currentFocus;
campo.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) {
        return false;
    }
    currentFocus = -1;
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + " autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    for (i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i].nombre.toUpperCase().includes(val.toUpperCase())) {
            var posicion_inicial = arreglo[i].nombre.indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
            var posicion_final = posicion_inicial + val.length;
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.innerHTML = arreglo[i].nombre.substr(0, posicion_inicial);
            b.innerHTML += "<strong>" + arreglo[i].nombre.substring(posicion_inicial, posicion_final) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arreglo[i].nombre.substr(posicion_final);
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='" + arreglo[i].id + "' value='" + arreglo[i].nombre + "'>";
            b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                campo.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                campo.id = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
                campo.readOnly = true;
                campo_oculto.value = campo.id;
                closeAllLists();
            });
            a.appendChild(b);
        }
    }
});
campo.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + " autocomplete-list");
    if (x)
        x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
            if (x)
                x[currentFocus].click();
        }
    }
});
function addActive(x) {
    if (!x)
        return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length)
        currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0)
        currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
}
function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
}
function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != campo) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}
```

Comment: No funcionó, estoy que creo otro autocomplete desde cero.

Comment: Entonces revisa en el DOM, quizás crea dinamicamente otro elemento, al cual debes aplicarle también la limpieza de datos